# Configuring elasticsearch to search and filter with has many / belongs to relationship

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a `Product` model where each `product` has many `sku`s.

I need to be able to search and filter via elasticsearch across both models, but not quite sure how to go about it.  I'm currently uploading to elasticsearch in this format:

```
[{
   id: 1
   title: 'Product 1'
   image: 'image1.jpg'
   skus: [{
     id: 1
     material: 'cotton'
     quantity: 4
   },{
     id: 2
     material: 'polyester'
     quantity: 22
   }]
},{
  ...
}]
```

I can search the title just fine, but I am unsure as to how I could do something like

- Search for title 'foobar' and filter by material 'cotton' and quantity > 5

Is this possible with elasticsearch?

*Edit*

I am open to uploading in a different format or using multiple indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [parent/child relationship](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html) is what you're looking for.

As a quick example, I can set up an index with a parent type and child type like this:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "mappings": {
       "product": {
         "properties": {
            "id": {
               "type": "long"
            },
            "image": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "title": {
               "type": "string"
            }
         }
      },
      "sku": {
          "_parent": {
             "type": "product"
          }, 
         "properties": {
            "id": {
               "type": "long"
            },
            "material": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "quantity": {
               "type": "long"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then add a parent document and two child documents:

```
POST /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_type":"product","_id":1}}
{"id": 1,"title": "Product1","image": "image1.jpg"}
{"index":{"_type":"sku", "_id":1,"_parent":1}}
{"id": 1,"material": "cotton","quantity": 4}
{"index":{"_type":"sku","_id":2,"_parent":1}}
{"id": 2,"material": "polyester","quantity": 22}
```

Now if I search for a `"product"` with `"title": "Product1"` that has a child `"sku"` with `"material": "cotton"` and `"quantity"` greater than 5, I won't find one:

```
POST /test_index/product/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match": {
               "title": "Product1"
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "has_child": {
               "type": "sku",
               "filter": {
                  "bool": {
                     "must": [
                        {
                           "term": {
                              "material": "cotton"
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "range": {
                              "quantity": {
                                 "gt": 5
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
   }
}
```

But if I search for a `"product"` with `"title": "Product1"` that has a child `"sku"` with `"material": "polyester"` and `"quantity"` greater than 5, I *will* find one:

```
POST /test_index/product/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match": {
               "title": "Product1"
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "has_child": {
               "type": "sku",
               "filter": {
                  "bool": {
                     "must": [
                        {
                           "term": {
                              "material": "polyester"
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "range": {
                              "quantity": {
                                 "gt": 5
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1.4054651,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "product",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1.4054651,
            "_source": {
               "id": 1,
               "title": "Product1",
               "image": "image1.jpg"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is some code I used for testing:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/d1989a28372ac9daae335d585601c11818b2fa11

Comment: This is great.  Is there any way to get the skus returned along with the products as children?

Comment: I think you'd have to do that with a second request. [`has_parent`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-parent-query.html) might be useful there.